# What does this return line actually represent?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What does an index of -1 represent in javascript when working with arrays, I get it returns me the last element in an array but why negative 1? I never learned this and it's hard to find on mdn.

```
if (arr.length === 0){
    return null;
}
else {
    return arr[arr.length -1];
}
```

Comment: An index of `-1` is not going to exist the majority of times. But an index of `arr.length -1` would be the last element. Simple arithmetic - an array with three elements will have `length = 3`. So `arr.length -1` is `2`.

Comment: It's subtracting 1 from the length of the array and returning the last element.

Comment: arr.length gives you the actual count of items, e.g. 5, but those items are indexed with 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. So the length, minus 1, is the index of the last element, e.g. 4

Comment: @j08691 Oh my god I didn't think of that I did not understand this for the life of me. That really helped me so much! u have a way with words random person ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index being used is not `-1`, it's `arr.length -1` - that is, "one less than the length of the array".

Why one less? Because array indexes start at zero:

- if you have an array with one item in, `arr.length` is 1, and `arr.length-1` is 0; so you access `arr[0]`, which is the first item in the array
- if you have an array with two items in, `arr.length` is 2, and you access `arr[1]`, the second item in the array
- and so on

The first if statement makes sure you *don't* try to access index -1 - if the array is empty, `arr.length` is 0, and you just return null